# Excel VBA - Text into Columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below strings of data in column B. I would like to shift text into different columns using Excel VBA 2007.  In the below example there are 4 groups of data, divided by "..". However, there can also be 2 or 3 groups of data.

Example 4 groups:

```
InstrumentBaseClass..Mega~Corporate~InstrumentBaseClass..Mid~Energy~InstrumentBaseClass..Micro~Oil Field Services
```

Example 2 groups:

```
InstrumentBaseClass..Mega~Corporate
```

How can I set text into different columns such that if there are only 2 sets of data, the two following columns say "none"? If there are 3 sets of data I need one column of "none" and so on.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your questions as solved,  you have neglected to do so in the past.

Comment: @rjk: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

An easy, no programmatic way is to simply fill all 4 columns with none and then let the text to columns feature over write any 'none's it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses hard coded inputs, but that could be replaced with range references or passed as varibles on calling the sub.

```
Sub TextDotColumns()

Dim sInput As String, sMid As String, rOutput As Object 'these should be passed when calling sub
Dim lBreak As Long, lColOff As Long, sCheck As String

sInput = "InstrumentBaseClass..Mega~Corporate~InstrumentBaseClass..Mid~Energy~InstrumentBaseClass..Micro~Oil Field Services"
sCheck = ".."
Set rOutput = Range("d10")

lBreak = InStr(1, sInput, sCheck, vbTextCompare)
rOutput.Select
lColOff = 1
Do While lBreak > 0
    sMid = Mid(sInput, 1, lBreak - 1)
    rOutput.Offset(1, lColOff).Value = sMid
    sInput = Right(sInput, Len(sInput) - lBreak - 1)
    lColOff = lColOff + 1
    lBreak = InStr(1, sInput, sCheck, vbTextCompare)
Loop

rOutput.Offset(1, lColOff).Value = sInput

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
Sub Test()

    '// Assumes your range is in column A
    With Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))        
        '// Text to columns
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Offset(, 1), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Other:=True, OtherChar:="."

        '// Fill blank spaces with "None"
        .Offset(, 1).Resize(, 4).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "None"
    End With

End Sub
```